# VB RadioButton into Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, radio-button

Trying to make an Airline Reservation program where the user inputs their name and then selects their seat via a radiobutton.

Once they reserve the seat the program is supposed to reset with the chosen seat no longer available for the next person to select their seat. So here is what I am confused about.

How do I get the previously "reserved" radiobuttons to change color and not selectable when the next person is choosing their seats. Eventually the plane will fill up and no more users can choose.

If there needs to be context or clarification for this I will be glad to add on more info.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you could use the TAG property to track whether it is available or not.

Comment: Just set the `Enabled` property to `False` for the seats already taken they they can't be selected

Comment: ...Or make the radio buttons hidden or invisible. There are so many ways to do this. Personally I would have thought that this should have been ironed out in the design stage, rather than the coding phase...

Comment: You can't really get the button itself to change color (without a lot of work), but you can get the background color of the button to change (the area surrounding the button), and like others said, you can enable or disable the button so it is not clickable. Also, just set button.clicked to true if it is already reserved.

Comment: Is there only ever one instance of this application running, or how are you handling concurrent bookings? Would have thought you'd need to reload and disable buttons already to manage that.

Comment: Use regular buttons and change the color. Once unavailable - disable it

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UpdateSeat()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        If arrSeatAvailableFirst(i) = False Then
            arrSeatFirst(i).BackColor = Color.DarkRed
            arrSeatFirst(i).Enabled = False


        End If
```

Then on the Click event for the button

```
Private Sub btnReserve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   btnReserve.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        If arrSeatFirst(i).Checked Then
            arrSeatAvailableFirst(i) = False
            radSelected = arrSeatFirst(i).Text
        Else
            arrSeatAvailableFirst(i) = True
        End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should help get you on your way. Just paste this directly into a blank WinForm application called `AirplaneSeats`; everything is added at runtime. Set a breakpoint and step through all the steps to see the details.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Windows.Forms


Public Class AirplaneSeats
    Private numberOfSeats As Integer = 30I
    Private SeatLayoutPanel As New FlowLayoutPanel With {.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight, .AutoScroll = True, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
    Private TableLayoutPanel1 As New TableLayoutPanel With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .ColumnCount = 1, .RowCount = 2}
    Private SubmitBtn As New Button With {.Text = "Submit", .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right}
    Private reservedSeats As New List(Of Int32)


    Private Sub AirplaneSeats_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        AddHandler Me.SubmitBtn.Click, AddressOf SubmitBtnClicked

        For i As Integer = 1I To numberOfSeats
            Dim seatRadio As New RadioButton With {.Text = "Seat " & i, .Tag = i, .Checked = False, .Enabled = True, .AutoCheck = True}
            AddHandler seatRadio.Click, AddressOf seatButtonClicked
            Me.SeatLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(seatRadio)
        Next

        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100.0!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100.0!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle())
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.SeatLayoutPanel, 0I, 0I)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.SubmitBtn, 0I, 1I)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TableLayoutPanel1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub seatButtonClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim selectedSeat As RadioButton
        If TypeOf sender Is RadioButton Then selectedSeat = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton) Else Exit Sub

        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.SeatLayoutPanel.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
                Dim ctrlRadio As RadioButton = DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButton)
                If CInt(ctrl.Tag) <> CInt(selectedSeat.Tag) Then
                    RemoveHandler ctrlRadio.Click, AddressOf Me.seatButtonClicked
                    ctrlRadio.Checked = False
                    AddHandler ctrlRadio.Click, AddressOf seatButtonClicked
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetSeatAvailability()
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.SeatLayoutPanel.Controls
            If Me.reservedSeats.Contains(CInt(ctrl.Tag)) Then ctrl.Enabled = False
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub SubmitBtnClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.SeatLayoutPanel.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Then
                Dim ctrlRadio As RadioButton = DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButton)
                If ctrlRadio.Checked Then
                    Me.reservedSeats.Add(CInt(ctrlRadio.Tag))
                    ctrlRadio.Checked = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        SetSeatAvailability()
    End Sub
End Class
```